# Understanding E3634A voltage control loop

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, control-system

I'm trying to understand the schematic of Agilent's E3634A. I found it's manual [here](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf4/88/8726/872509-agilent_technologies/e3634a.pdf?172beae2a45b7b3843fd1a3fe7ceda28) (Relevant schematic on page 129). I've extracted and annotated the area of interest below:
[image: E3634A control loop]

I'm pretty sure the three op-amps in the center and bottom right implement the voltage control loop. The sense inputs go into a difference amplifier. From that point on however, I'm not sure anymore. It looks like the measured output voltage and the set voltage ("CV_REF" from the DAC) are summed and go into the noninverting input of the center left amplifier. I can't see how there is negative feedback in this topology as the inverting input is just tied to ground.

In the schematics I have seen so far, the measured voltage is fed into the error amplifier's inverting input and the set voltage goes into the noninverting input. How does it work here?

Comment: Without showing which of the "V-sense inputs" connects to the positive terminal and which one connects to the negative terminal, there's no way we can determine whether the result is inverting or not.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, thanks for the hint! It is actually wired "backwards" and there is a small comment "0~-5.625v" on the schematic indicating that. I falsely assumed it was noninverting because it seemed the only sensible thing to me, so I didn't include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower opamp is indeed a difference amplifier.

Note how it and the opamp fed by the DAC are both connected to the non-inverting input of the next stage through a 30k resistor. The feed-back loop will steer this node to ground (as you correctly remarked). This is the case when both opamps output the same voltage (in magnitude), but with opposite polarity.

You can also see it like this: the difference amplifier sends some current through R108. That same current must also be sunk by the DAC amp. When the two voltages (commanded and actual) agree, the center tap of the R108, R107 divider is at 0V.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the puzzle piece I was missing. I also realized that the DAC voltage is negative, so the inverting amp turns it positive. The difference amp is also wired "backwards" so that a positive sense voltage gives a negative result (as annotated on the schematic... I missed the minus sign)